# How do I match records which have a certain entry IN their rdfs:label attribute?

Tags: list, contains, sparql

I'm trying to query dbpedia for programming languages like D by name:

[http://dbpedia.org/page/D_(programming_language)](http://dbpedia.org/page/D_%28programming_language%29)

And I figure `rdfs:label` is a good way to do this. But I'm having trouble coming up with syntax for searching by labels containing "D (programming language)". In dpbedia, `rdfs:labels` aren't simply strings, they're more like lists. How do I filter for records that have a certain entry IN the `rdfs:label`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works in [dbpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql)! Based on AndyS's answer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?lang {
    ?lang rdf:type <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ProgrammingLanguage> .
    ?lang rdfs:label "D (programming language)"@en
}
Limit 1
```